# MAUI MAP - How to get the business type and name from Location?

Tags: geolocation, maui

I've been trying to get the business name or at least type of business with the reverse geocoding/Placemark.
I'm just getting numbers for some things. For example FeatureName is 230. Anyone knows how to translate it?
If this is not the correct way, how can get the required information?

This is the code example -

```
private async Task<string> GetGeocodeReverseData(double latitude = 43.01297, double longitude = -88.38205)
        {
            IEnumerable<Placemark> placemarks = await Geocoding.Default.GetPlacemarksAsync(latitude, longitude);
            Placemark placemark = placemarks?.FirstOrDefault();

            if (placemark != null)
            {
                return
                    $"AdminArea:       {placemark.AdminArea}\n" +
                    $"CountryCode:     {placemark.CountryCode}\n" +
                    $"CountryName:     {placemark.CountryName}\n" +
                    $"FeatureName:     {placemark.FeatureName}\n" +
                    $"Locality:        {placemark.Locality}\n" +
                    $"PostalCode:      {placemark.PostalCode}\n" +
                    $"SubAdminArea:    {placemark.SubAdminArea}\n" +
                    $"SubLocality:     {placemark.SubLocality}\n" +
                    $"SubThoroughfare: {placemark.SubThoroughfare}\n" +
                    $"Thoroughfare:    {placemark.Thoroughfare}\n";

            }

            return "";
        }
```

I would like to get the business name and/or type of business. There is a gas station at this location.

This is the output I'm getting.

```
AdminArea: "Wisconsin"
CountryCode: "US"
CountryName: "United States"
FeatureName: "230"
Locality: "Wales"
Location: {Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors.Location}
PostalCode: "53183"
SubAdminArea: "Waukesha County"
SubLocality: (null)
SubThoroughfare: "230"
Thoroughfare: "West Summit Avenue"
```

Comment: please provide a specific example, what you expect it to return, and what it actually returns

Comment: Thanks for responding. Added the code above.

Comment: Please provide a **specific example** of a location that is returning bad data, the actual result, and the expected result

Comment: Hi Jason, look at the default values. I trimmed them down.

Comment: I can't help you if you don't provide the requested information

Comment: This is the gas station at that location. Looking to get that info in the code.
https://www.google.com/maps/place/TOBACCO+OUTLET+PLUS+GROC+%23358/@43.0128785,-88.3813714,18.63z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x8805b09f54c0121d:0xfc67596509a7a57e!8m2!3d43.0129914!4d-88.3819667!16s%2Fg%2F1tfh_4tl?entry=ttu

Comment: **the actual result, and the expected result**.  I want to see the **data** you get back from the API, not a link to a map

Comment: This is all new to me. I don't know what to expect from this. That's why I asked question. I know what I'm looking for. I added what I'm getting to the OP.

Comment: @May What do you mean the business name and/or type of business? Can you help give an example?